# Ref для ссылочных типов

Tags: c#

Скажите есть ли смысл передавать в метод аргументы ссылочного типа с модификатором ref (а также out)
Ведь ссылочные типы передаются в качестве аргументов и так по ссылке?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Имеет, если вы хотите менять переданную ссылку (а не состояние объекта, на который она указывает) внутри метода.

Comment: Всегда представляю такую аналогию из более низкоуровневых языков: передача ссылочного типа - передача указателя на объект; передача ссылочного типа с модификатором ref/out - передача указателя на указатель на объект. Отсюда и все вытекающие последствия

Comment: добавлю что к свойствам ссылку нужно давать через поле этого свойства, так что автосвойство немного не подходит.

Answer (score 6):

К правильному ответу [@Flammable](/users/10467/flammable) добавлю: в .NET не происходит передача аргументов ссылочных типов по ссылке. Передача аргументов происходит по значению. Разница в том, что для аргументов с типами-значениями по значению передаётся *сам объект*, а для аргументов со ссылочного типа — *ссылка* на объект.

Это не должно быть неожиданностью, так же ведут себя и переменные типов-значений и ссылочных типов.

Теперь видно, что `out` и `ref` работают в обоих случаях одинаково: они гарантируют, что изменение в переданной переменной (сам объект для типа-значения и ссылка для ссылочных типов) будут видны вызывающей функции.