# Зачем в метод Array.Resize() передавать массив по ссылке?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, ref

У абстрактного класса Array есть статический метод `Array.Resize(ref T[] array, int newSize)`, который как вы видите первый параметр принимает по ссылке.

К примеру, рассмотрим вот такой код:

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3 };  

    Array.Resize(ref intArray, 2); 
}
```

**1)** Зачем передавать `intArray` по ссылке, ведь все массивы так и так ссылочного типа?

**2)** Быть может это уберегает от написания такого

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] intArray4;

    Array.Resize(ref intArray, 2);
}
```

Здесь возникнет ошибка на стадии компиляции, т.к. `ref` требует чтобы `intArray` был инициализирован вызывающим кодом. Но ведь можно инициализировать значением `null`:

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] intArray4 = null;  

    Array.Resize(ref intArray, 2); 
}
```

и мне кажется смысл теряется, или нет?

---

### ВОПРОС

В чем польза использования `ref` с ссылочными типами?

---

### ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ

После того как был опубликованный данный пост, участником сообщества было отмечено, что возможно это дубликат и я был направлен на статью [Ref для ссылочных типов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/227604/14935). Статья ввела меня по больше в курс дела, но ответа я там не нашел. Оказывается, даже для себя самого вопрос четко не был сформулирован. Но после ответа @velial и + дополнительно прочитанной статьи [Передача параметров ссылочного типа](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters) я понял в чем запутался: **Я не понимал, что `Array.Resize()` в своей работе ведь создает новый массив для которого выделяет отдельную память в куче** и он ссылку на эту память создает новую или использует существующую, вот где "падла зарыта".

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ref для ссылочных типов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/227604/ref-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Суть в том, что любая переменная - это значение.

Переменная ссылочного типа не исключение - её значением является **ссылка** на какой-то объект (да, массив - тоже объект).

Соответственно, вызывая `Array.Resize(ref intArray, 2)`, мы подразумеваем что значение **ссылки** может измениться в результате вызова данного метода.

Другими словами, даём функции `Array.Resize()` на вход один массив, а получаем на выходе совершенно другой массив.

Попробуйте выполнить следующий пример, затем убрать ключевое слово `ref` из объявления и вызова функции `ExtendArray()`, и снова выполнить :)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Solution
{
    static void ExtendArray<T>(ref T[] array, T new_value)
    {
        if (array != null)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length + 1);
            array[array.Length - 1] = new_value;
        }
        else
            array = new T[] { new_value };
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] data = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

        Console.Write("До вызова ExtendArray: \n  {0}\n", string.Join(", ", data.Select(v => v.ToString())));
        ExtendArray(ref data, 4);
        Console.Write("После вызова ExtendArray: \n  {0}\n", string.Join(", ", data.Select(v => v.ToString())));
    }
}
```

При наличии ключевого слова `ref` имеем следующий вывод:

> До вызова ExtendArray:
>
> 0, 1, 2, 3
>
> После вызова ExtendArray:
>
> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Что из этого следует - в вызывающем коде (функция Main()) переменная `data` изменила своё значение и стала указывать **на другой массив**. Потому что передавалась **по ссылке** с ключевым словом `ref`.

В отсутствие ключевого слова `ref` имеем следующий вывод:

> До вызова ExtendArray:
>
> 0, 1, 2, 3
>
> После вызова ExtendArray:
>
> 0, 1, 2, 3

Что имеем здесь - внутри функции `ExtendArray()` новый массив если и создаётся, то в вызывающем коде переменная `data` продолжает указывать на старую версию массива - да, именно потому, что сама ссылка на массив передавалась **по значению**, а не по ссылке.

Да, если Вы никогда не кодили на таких языках как `C++` и `Pascal`, то фраза "ссылка на ссылку" может звучать не очень красиво.

Но тем не менее, в этом нет ничего "криминального" :)

Comment: Правильно ли я понял: к примеру, переменная `intArray` хранит ссылку-адрес `0x12345`. И если я хочу быть уверен, что `Array.Resize()` не изменит это и по окончанию работы `Array.Resize()` сохранится `intArray=0x12345`, то в таком случаи я должен передать эту переменную через `ref` и произойдет следующее: в стеке создаться некая новая переменная со значением `0x34567` которая будет указывать на `0x12345`?

Comment: Вы пишите _Другими словами, даём функции Array.Resize() на вход один массив, а получаем на выходе совершенно другой массив_. Т.е. `массив` как фиксированный набор (структура) данных не может менять свою размерность и поэтому свой результат `Array.Resize()` размещает в другом месте кучи, так?

Comment: да, Вы правильно понимаете, что массив не может менять свою размерность и поэтому результат `Array.Resize()` возвращает новый массив, у которого другой адрес в куче.

Comment: + [ссылка на реализацию `Array.Resize()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,71074deaf111c4e3)