# Передача объекта в метод

Tags: c#

Вопрос из серии "данет" и "дубликат, гуглить не умеешь".

Мне нужно передавать объект по цепочке в несколько методов, при этом мне нужны только значения в объекте, сам объект менять не нужно.

Есть я напишу

```
void Q(MyClass myClass) {
    W(myClass);
}
void W(MyClass myClass) {
    E(myClass);
}
void E(MyClass myClass) {
    R(myClass);
}
```

то каждый раз будет создан новый объект? Нужно ли при передаче указывать ref?

Comment: нет, нет *(7 символов нужно...)*

Comment: @Igor благодарю

Comment: я дополню еще: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/227604/ref-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2 А ссылочный тип на то и ссылочный... =)

Answer (score 2):

Не особо относится к вопросу, но я хочу поделиться. 
Для выстраивания цепочек вызовов, вы можете объявить методы, которые принимают ваш объект и возвращают ваш объект. Например, у нас есть класс

```
public class MyObject { }
```

И есть методы

```
public MyObject A(MyObject obj) 
{
    return obj;
}

public MyObject B(MyObject obj)
{
    return obj;
}

public MyObject C(MyObject obj)
{
    return obj;
}
```

тогда цепочка может выглядеть так:

```
var obj = new MyObject();
C(B(A(obj)));
```

Ну, или, если методы можно сделать статическими, их можно оформить методами расширения, например

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static MyObject A(this MyObject obj)
    {
        return obj;
    }

    public static MyObject B(this MyObject obj)
    {
        return obj;
    }

    public static MyObject C(this MyObject obj)
    {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Тогда та же самая цепочка будет

```
var obj = new MyObject();
obj.A().B().C();
```